# Gatlin tests run against a IIS server expecting integrated security fail with 401

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

As the title suggests. We are using Gatling 3.3.1 and attempting to write tests against a service running on IIS that is expecting windows credentials to be sent (Integrated Security). When the URL being tested is run in a browser everything is fine but run through gatling a 401 is thrown.

When looking at the IIS logs its apparent that user info is not being passed from gatling but is visible for the requests from the browser. I've looked through the docs and don't see anything.  I've tried things like adding .header("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM") to the HTTP item but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Gatling creator here.

Sadly, NTLM is a legacy MS Windows specific authentication scheme and we don't support it at the moment.

Supporting it would be quite an effort: getting familiar with the spec (assuming there's one) + implementing + setting up a test environment. And as it's a legacy scheme, there's simply not enough of a market to justify the investment on our side.
So I don't expect it to happen unless it gets contributed or someone contracts with us to implement it.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Are there any supported protocols that utilize Active Directory?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It looks like ForgeRock has implemented an LDAP plugin but no idea if they've actually open sourced it, see https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENDJ-2800